# Why isn't my javascript not working with django

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am  a beginner in django. I have no problem with the back-end but my front-end has some problem with javascript (specifically `addEventListener` doesn't work). I've tried everything from adding External js to adding internal js nothing seems to work. But the js connect with django and its being loaded, but the function doesn't work and no error seems to log in the console.

It is just a click function, which should toggle a classname in html while clicked. By the way I'm inheriting my nav file. i hope that doesn't cause any problem.

My internal js file:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    // EVENT LISTENER FOR NAV FUNCTION
    let nav_btn = document.querySelector('.user-pr')
    nav_btn.addEventListener('click', navfunc)
    function navfunc() {
        nav_btn.classList.toggle('active')
        console.log("click")
    }
    
</script>
```

My Settings.py file (Static Config):

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'Assets')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

I've checked StackOverflow for similar questions, but nothing match my scenario.

Comment: Hi, the script tag is inside the html file?

Comment: Is the `querySelector` able to find `.user-pr`? What happens when you console log the `nav_btn` just after it was defined? Is the script inside the html file or in separate .js file? Is the script tag below or above the `.user-pr` element? If you are using this script as an external file did you include the `{% load static %}` template tag and `scr="{% static 'path/to/script.js' %}"` attribute?

Comment: Answers for all Your Above Asked question are yes, the query selector gets it, and this is a internal js file which means its in the html file. the content loads and shows up in the console but no action is done, it just remains still, and no errors are logged